# Google Chrome Frame - custom install dialog with "onmissing"

Tags: google-chrome-frame

Can anyone point me at an example of a customized Google Chrome Frame install dialog?

It looks like GCF allows you to hide the default dialog as a parameter to `CFInstall.check()`  (`onmissing`, `preventPrompt`) but I haven't been able to find an example of what the expected structure of `onmissing` is.

I can have `onmissing` launch a custom dialog of my own, with jQuery or similar, but don't know exactly where to link to in order to start the install process correctly.  Whenever I redirect to the installer directly, I get prompted for an admin password, unlike when I use the default GCF install dialog.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this [article](http://www.michaeldunbar.com/articles/blog/2011/november/using-google-chrome-frame.aspx) helped me . Check it out.

Comment: This didn't address my question.  I had already figured out how to launch my own custom dialog, but I can't figure out what link I need to install without admin rights.